# why cant i print a id within a html attribute element using php

Tags: php, jquery, html

guys i have a problem in outputting the id in php. what i'm trying to do is create a article and when the user clicks the edit button the text area shows up for editing while the original article hides. i'm using both jquery and php to do it. the problem is that when the user clicks the edit button the hidden text area doesn't showup when i looked in to the browser source i found that the id is not outputting in the hidden textarea. so, please guide me on how to print the id in the hidden area.
here is the code for jquery :

```
$(".hidden_text_edit").click(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr("id");


$(".hidden_edit_4_session").find("id").show();    

var hide_status=$(".statusboxes").attr('type');

var title=$(".title_s_2copy").attr('type');

var data=$(".data_s_2copy").attr('type');

$(hide_status).hide();

//tinyMCE.get('.hidden_edit_4_session').setContent(data);

$(".title_s_edit").val(title);

});

$(".close_edit").click(function(){

    $(".hidden_edit_4_session").hide();    

var hide_status=$(".statusboxes").attr('div', 'type');

$(hide_status).show();

});
```

code for article and hidden text area logic:

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['app'])){

    $statusui="<div class='jumbotron'><input type='text' class='form-control title_s' name='status_title' placeholder='Title ' ><br>"
            . "<textarea id='wall_id_1' class='update_session' placeholder='whats up ".$session_uname."'>"
            . "</textarea>"
            . "<button style='float:right;' type='a' class='btn btn-warning btn btn-large btn-lg post-s'>Post</button></div>";
 $statusui_edit="<div id=".$updateid." class='hidden_edit_4_session".$updateid." jumbotron'><a href='#' class='pull-right close_edit' title='Close without editing'>Close X</a><input type='text' class='form-control title_s_edit' name='status_title' value='".html_entity_decode($title)."' placeholder='Title' ><div>&nbsp;</div>"
            . "<textarea id='wall_edit_1' value='".html_entity_decode($data)."' class='session_edit' placeholder='whats up ".$session_uname."'>"
            . "" .html_entity_decode($data)."</textarea><br>"
            . "<button style='float:right;' type='a' class='btn btn-warning btn btn-large btn-lg post-s-edit'>Update</button></div>";


}
 elseif ($is_friend==TRUE&&$session_uname!=$f_uname) {
       $statusui="<input type='text' class='form-control title_f' name='status_title' placeholder='Title'><br>"
               . "<textarea id='wall_id_1' type='c' value='".html_entity_decode($data)." class='status_4_expresspad_friend' style='' placeholder='hi ".$session_uname." want to say something to ".$f_uname.". '>"
               . "</textarea><br>"
               . "<button style='float:right;' class='btn btn-warning btn-large btn-lg post-f'>Post</button><br><br><br><div>&nbsp;</div>";
       $statusui_edit="<div class='hidden_edit_4_friend jumbotron'><a title='Close without editing' href='#' class='pull-right close_edit_f'>Close X</a><input type='text' class='form-control title_f_edit' name='status_title' value='".html_entity_decode($title)."' placeholder='Title'><br>"
               . "<textarea id='wall_edit_2' value='".html_entity_decode($data)."' class='update_4_expresspad'placeholder='hi ".$session_uname." want to say something to ".$f_uname.". '>"
               . "</textarea><br>"
               . "<button style='float:right;' type='c' class='btn btn-warning btn-large btn-lg post-f-edit'>Update</button>";
}

?>
```

here is the code where the status list is outputting in a loop with the hidden text area's logic:

```
<?php


$status2view=$project->statusView($session_uname, $f_uname);
//gives output on var dump
#row vars to extract user's update data.




    foreach($status2view as $row){
           $id=$row['update_id'];






$status_replies_=$project->reply2StatusView($id);




foreach ($status_replies_ as $row) {

                $status_reply_id=$row['update_id'];
                $reply_author=$row['author'];
                $reply_d=htmlentities($row['update_body']);
                $reply_data=  stripslashes($reply_d);
                $reply_t=  htmlentities($row['title']);
                $reply_title=  stripslashes($reply_t);
                $account_name=$row['account_name'];
               $reply_date=$row['time'];
               $reply_delete_button="";
               if ($reply_author==$session_uname || $account_name==$session_uname) {
                   $reply_delete_button="<li><span id='$status_reply_id' class='delete_reply_btn glyphicon glyphicon-remove'><a href='#' title='Delete this comment'>Remove X</a></span></li>";
               }
              $status_replies="<div id='".$status_reply_id."' class='replyboxes'><b>Reply by<a href='search_results.php?u=".$reply_author."'>".$reply_author."</a>".$reply_date ."<legend>"
                       . "<b class='caret'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle pull-right' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-expanded='true' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>
                        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>".$reply_delete_button." "
                      . "<li><a href='#' class='hidden_text_area glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' title='Edit this comment' >Edit</a></li>"
                      . "<li><a href='report.php?u='".$reply_author."'>Report</a><li></ul>"
                      . "</button></b></legend><br>".  html_entity_decode($reply_data)."";
            }
        }

     foreach ($status2view as $row1) {

         //got values here.
                $updateid=$row1['update_id'];
                $account_name=$row1['account_name'];
                $os_id=$row1['os_id'];
                $author=$row1['author'];
                $post_date=$row1['time'];
                $title= $row1['title'];
                $data= $row1['update_body'];
                $statusdeletebutton='';
                if ($author==$session_uname || $account_name==$session_uname) {
                $statusdeletebutton='<li>'
                           . '<a href="#" id="'.$updateid.'" class="delete_4_session hidden_text_delete_'.$updateid.' glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_reply_btn" title="Delete this status and its replies">Remove</a></li>';
                }
                $status_list= '<div id="'.$updateid.'" type="'.$updateid.'" class="statusboxes jumbotron">'
                        . '<h3 style="color:black; margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:5px;" class="pull-left"><div id="'.$updateid.'" class="title_s_2copy" value="'.html_entity_decode($title).'">'.html_entity_decode($title).'</div></h3>'
                        . '<span class="pull-right">'
                        . '<div class="dropdown">'
                        . '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  >'
                        . '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>'
                        . '<ul class="dropdown-menu">'
                        . '<li><a href="#" id="'.$updateid.'" type="'.$updateid.'" class="edit_4_session hidden_text_edit glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit this status" >Edit</a></li>'.$statusdeletebutton.'</ul></div></span><br><hr><span class="pull-left data_s_2copy" id="'.$updateid.'" value="'.html_entity_decode($data).'" style="font-size:9px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px; text-align:left; color:black;">'
                        . html_entity_decode($data).'</span><br><br><hr><b style="text-align:right; color:black;"><small>Posted by:-  <a href="search_results.php?u='.$author.'">'.$author.   '</a>   '.$post_date.'</small></b>'
                        . '<br>'.$status_replies.'<br>'.$statusui_edit;


                if ($is_friend==TRUE||$session_uname==$f_uname) {
                    $status_list.= '<textarea id="'.$updateid.'"  class="status_update input-custom2" placeholder="comment\'s"></textarea>'
                            . '<button id="'.$updateid.'" type="b" class="btn btn-warning pull-right btn-sm">Reply</button></div>';


                    }
                    echo $status_list;
                }
```

here is the browsers page source:-

```
<div class='jumbotron'><input type='text' class='form-control title_s' name='status_title' placeholder='Title ' ><br><textarea id='wall_id_1' class='update_session' placeholder='whats up qwerty'></textarea><button style='float:right;' type='a' class='btn btn-warning btn btn-large btn-lg post-s'>Post</button></div><div id="7" type="7" class="statusboxes jumbotron"><h3 style="color:black; margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:5px;" class="pull-left"><div id="7" class="title_s_2copy" value="hello shan!">hello shan!</div></h3><span class="pull-right"><div class="dropdown"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="#" id="7" type="7" class="edit_4_session hidden_text_edit glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit this status" >Edit</a></li><li><a href="#" id="7" class="delete_4_session hidden_text_delete_7 glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_reply_btn" title="Delete this status and its replies">Remove</a></li></ul></div></span><br><hr><span class="pull-left data_s_2copy" id="7" value="<p>what's up.</p>" style="font-size:9px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px; text-align:left; color:black;"><p>what's up.</p></span><br><br><hr><b style="text-align:right; color:black;"><small>Posted by:-  <a href="search_results.php?u=qwerty">qwerty</a>   2015-10-20 10:13:18</small></b><br><br><div id='' class='hidden_edit_4_session jumbotron'><a href='#' class='pull-right close_edit' title='Close without editing'>Close X</a><input type='text' class='form-control title_s_edit' name='status_title' value='' placeholder='Title' ><div>&nbsp;</div><textarea id='wall_edit_1' value='' class='session_edit' placeholder='whats up qwerty'></textarea><br><button style='float:right;' type='a' class='btn btn-warning btn btn-large btn-lg post-s-edit'>Update</button></div><textarea id="7"  class="status_update input-custom2" placeholder="comment's"></textarea><button id="7" type="b" class="btn btn-warning pull-right btn-sm">Reply</button></div><div id="6" type="6" class="statusboxes jumbotron"><h3 style="color:black; margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:5px;" class="pull-left"><div id="6" class="title_s_2copy" value="pen test">pen test</div></h3><span class="pull-right"><div class="dropdown"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="#" id="6" type="6" class="edit_4_session hidden_text_edit glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit this status" >Edit</a></li><li><a href="#" id="6" class="delete_4_session hidden_text_delete_6 glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_reply_btn" title="Delete this status and its replies">Remove</a></li></ul></div></span><br><hr><span class="pull-left data_s_2copy" id="6" value="<p>&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;alert("hooya hacked")&lt;/script&gt;</p>" style="font-size:9px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px; text-align:left; color:black;"><p>&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;alert("hooya hacked")&lt;/script&gt;</p></span><br><br><hr><b style="text-align:right; color:black;"><small>Posted by:-  <a href="search_results.php?u=qwerty">qwerty</a>   2015-10-18 21:53:31</small></b><br><br><div id='' class='hidden_edit_4_session jumbotron'><a href='#' class='pull-right close_edit' title='Close without editing'>Close X</a><input type='text' class='form-control title_s_edit' name='status_title' value='' placeholder='Title' ><div>&nbsp;</div><textarea id='wall_edit_1' value='' class='session_edit' placeholder='whats up qwerty'></textarea><br><button style='float:right;' type='a' class='btn btn-warning btn btn-large btn-lg post-s-edit'>Update</button></div><textarea id="6"  class="status_update input-custom2" placeholder="comment's"></textarea><button id="6" type="b" class="btn btn-warning pull-right btn-sm">Reply</button></div><div id="5" type="5" class="statusboxes jumbotron"><h3 style="color:black; margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:5px;" class="pull-left"><div id="5" class="title_s_2copy" value="pen test">pen test</div></h3><span class="pull-right"><div class="dropdown"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="#" id="5" type="5" class="edit_4_session hidden_text_edit glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit this status" >Edit</a></li><li><a href="#" id="5" class="delete_4_session hidden_text_delete_5 glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_reply_btn" title="Delete this status and its replies">Remove</a></li></ul></div></span><br><hr><span class="pull-left data_s_2copy" id="5" value="<p>&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;alert("hooya hacked")&lt;/script&gt;</p>" style="font-size:9px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px; text-align:left; color:black;"><p>&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;alert("hooya hacked")&lt;/script&gt;</p></span><br><br><hr><b style="text-align:right; color:black;"><small>Posted by:-  <a href="search_results.php?u=qwerty">qwerty</a>   2015-10-18 21:53:30</small></b><br><br><div id='' class='hidden_edit_4_session jumbotron'><a href='#' class='pull-right close_edit' title='Close without editing'>Close X</a><input type='text' class='form-control title_s_edit' name='status_title' value='' placeholder='Title' ><div>&nbsp;</div><textarea id='wall_edit_1' value='' class='session_edit' placeholder='whats up qwerty'></textarea><br><button style='float:right;' type='a' class='btn btn-warning btn btn-large btn-lg post-s-edit'>Update</button></div><textarea id="5"  class="status_update input-custom2" placeholder="comment's"></textarea><button id="5" type="b" class="btn btn-warning pull-right btn-sm">Reply</button></div><div id="3" type="3" class="statusboxes jumbotron"><h3 style="color:black; margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:5px;" class="pull-left"><div id="3" class="title_s_2copy" value="this is not working">this is not working</div></h3><span class="pull-right"><div class="dropdown"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="#" id="3" type="3" class="edit_4_session hidden_text_edit glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit this status" >Edit</a></li><li><a href="#" id="3" class="delete_4_session hidden_text_delete_3 glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_reply_btn" title="Delete this status and its replies">Remove</a></li></ul></div></span><br><hr><span class="pull-left data_s_2copy" id="3" value="<p>wht to do???</p>" style="font-size:9px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px; text-align:left; color:black;"><p>wht to do???</p></span><br><br><hr><b style="text-align:right; color:black;"><small>Posted by:-  <a href="search_results.php?u=qwerty">qwerty</a>   2015-10-17 19:32:35</small></b><br><br><div id='' class='hidden_edit_4_session jumbotron'><a href='#' class='pull-right close_edit' title='Close without editing'>Close X</a><input type='text' class='form-control title_s_edit' name='status_title' value='' placeholder='Title' ><div>&nbsp;</div><textarea id='wall_edit_1' value='' class='session_edit' placeholder='whats up qwerty'></textarea><br><button style='float:right;' type='a' class='btn btn-warning btn btn-large btn-lg post-s-edit'>Update</button></div><textarea id="3"  class="status_update input-custom2" placeholder="comment's"></textarea><button id="3" type="b" class="btn btn-warning pull-right btn-sm">Reply</button></div><div id="2" type="2" class="statusboxes jumbotron"><h3 style="color:black; margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:5px;" class="pull-left"><div id="2" class="title_s_2copy" value="im grateful to mother nature and god">im grateful to mother nature and god</div></h3><span class="pull-right"><div class="dropdown"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="#" id="2" type="2" class="edit_4_session hidden_text_edit glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit this status" >Edit</a></li><li><a href="#" id="2" class="delete_4_session hidden_text_delete_2 glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_reply_btn" title="Delete this status and its replies">Remove</a></li></ul></div></span><br><hr><span class="pull-left data_s_2copy" id="2" value="<p>as the title says im grateful</p>" style="font-size:9px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px; text-align:left; color:black;"><p>as the title says im grateful</p></span><br><br><hr><b style="text-align:right; color:black;"><small>Posted by:-  <a href="search_results.php?u=qwerty">qwerty</a>   2015-10-17 19:29:15</small></b><br><br><div id='' class='hidden_edit_4_session jumbotron'><a href='#' class='pull-right close_edit' title='Close without editing'>Close X</a><input type='text' class='form-control title_s_edit' name='status_title' value='' placeholder='Title' ><div>&nbsp;</div><textarea id='wall_edit_1' value='' class='session_edit' placeholder='whats up qwerty'></textarea><br><button style='float:right;' type='a' class='btn btn-warning btn btn-large btn-lg post-s-edit'>Update</button></div><textarea id="2"  class="status_update input-custom2" placeholder="comment's"></textarea><button id="2" type="b" class="btn btn-warning pull-right btn-sm">Reply</button></div><div id="1" type="1" class="statusboxes jumbotron"><h3 style="color:black; margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:5px;" class="pull-left"><div id="1" class="title_s_2copy" value="hello world">hello world</div></h3><span class="pull-right"><div class="dropdown"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="#" id="1" type="1" class="edit_4_session hidden_text_edit glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit this status" >Edit</a></li><li><a href="#" id="1" class="delete_4_session hidden_text_delete_1 glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_reply_btn" title="Delete this status and its replies">Remove</a></li></ul></div></span><br><hr><span class="pull-left data_s_2copy" id="1" value="<p>this is my 1st post</p>" style="font-size:9px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px; text-align:left; color:black;"><p>this is my 1st post</p></span><br><br><hr><b style="text-align:right; color:black;"><small>Posted by:-  <a href="search_results.php?u=qwerty">qwerty</a>   2015-10-17 19:25:09</small></b><br><br><div id='' class='hidden_edit_4_session jumbotron'><a href='#' class='pull-right close_edit' title='Close without editing'>Close X</a><input type='text' class='form-control title_s_edit' name='status_title' value='' placeholder='Title' ><div>&nbsp;</div><textarea id='wall_edit_1' value='' class='session_edit' placeholder='whats up qwerty'></textarea><br><button style='float:right;' type='a' class='btn btn-warning btn btn-large btn-lg post-s-edit'>Update</button></div><textarea id="1"  class="status_update input-custom2" placeholder="comment's"></textarea><button id="1" type="b" class="btn btn-warning pull-right btn-sm">Reply</button></div>    </div>
```

Comment: why was my question downvoted???

Answer (score 0):

Your code problem is with the naming of ids since they are all numbers

For HTML 4, ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").
HTML 5 is even more permissive, saying only that an id must contain at least one character and may not contain any space characters.

[What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)